# Submit text to controller, return text result and enter into div

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

This is a simplification as the HTLM is rendered via back end DB, but I want to enter a search string to the controller, and then inject the returned results as HTML into a div

The ajax query is hitting the controller and returning the correct string but

1. The input text value is being sent as Nothing
2. The returned string (that is correct) is not updating the div

Any ideas?

Thank you

The HTML

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin-right: 25px;">
<input type="text" id="SearchTextBox" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Search..."  name="query" value="">
<div class="input-group-btn">
<button type="submit" onclick="onChangeSearch();" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content" id="main">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

<div id="SearchResults" class="search_results" id="SearchDiv"><p> Search Results</p>
</div>
```

The jQuery function

```
<script>

function onChangeSearch() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SearchBox", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#SearchTextBox').val(),
        success: function (data) {
            //$('#SearchDiv').html(data);
            $('#SearchDiv').replaceWith(data);
            alert(data);
        }

    });
}
```

The controller (have tried a number of variations on this, including JavaScriptResult).

```
<HttpPost()>
Function SearchBox(SearchText As String) As String
    Try
        Dim vMessage As String = "<p>No results for " & SearchText & "</p>"

        Return vMessage
        'Return JavaScript(SB.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

====================================================================
EDIT - figured out why the results were not being entered - had two ID's for the div! Stared at that for hours and didn't spot it until I posted this! Sigh!

## Still having an issue with the submitted string though....

Comment: Try the ajax call with `data: { query: $('#SearchTextBox').val() }`, so that it arrives on your server as a `query` variable. Secondly, your result `div` has two `id` attributes which will be the cause of not seeing the results.

Comment: Hi trincot - must have been editing the question as you posted your answer, spotted the duplicate ID's. Changed the jQuery script as you suggested, but it's still sending a result of Nothing

Comment: Clearly having one of those stupid days - I used 'query' as a literal instead of 'SearchText' that is in the function. Spend so little time with MVC I forget the basics... If you want to enter that as an answer I can mark it up as such. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the ajax data as a key/value pair, so for instance:

```
 data: { SearchText: $('#SearchTextBox').val() }
```

This will it will arrive on your server as a `SearchText` variable.

Secondly, your result `div` had two `id` attributes (in your original question) which will be the cause of not seeing the results.